# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50501) with this library (version 0x50201)

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have installed `Shadowsocks-Qt5` within the code `sudo apt-get install shadowsocks-qt5` in terminal, and then I can find the launch icon by searching, but it won't open when I click the icon. Then I tried to use terminal to open it, but the error comes out as below:

```
~ ss-qt5
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50501) with this library (version 0x50201)
[1]    8875 abort (core dumped)  ss-qt5
```

I searched many answers but no one work. I think the key may be the default Qt library, but I don't know how to set default Qt library, the system on my computer is `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

After so many months of trying to fix this issue, this helped me.

sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins.

Comment: I had to remove that package to fix mine.

Comment: On Manjaro, uninstalling and reinstalling `qt5-styleplugins` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this error when attempting to run Qt Creator after doing a system update.  For me, I was attempting to run Qt Creator 4.10.0-rc1 (based on Qt 5.13.1) that I had manually installed to ~/Qt along with Qt 5.13.0, and my system has Qt 5.12.2 installed.

I was getting the following error:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c02) with this library (version 0x50d00)
```

Doing an `strace` when running qtcreator.sh revealed that it was attempting to load plugins from the system directory.  I finally discovered the culprit was the environment variable `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` was set (in my case to `/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins:/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/kcms`).

After unsetting this variable, Qt Creator started up and worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, and even after 4 hours of debugging, I got nowhere. Finally, I found the following way to keep separate Qt versions, posting here so that other people find it.

Suppose you installed Qt in `${QtRoot}`, extend the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export PATH=${QtRoot}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${QtRoot}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

You can make a wrapper function / script to manage separate Qt installations like this:

```
QtVersion=5.12.8

QtRoot="/scratch/Qt/${QtVersion}/gcc_64"

export PATH=${QtRoot}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${QtRoot}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

After running this your application will likely run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be happening if your Qt installation is partially of different versions

I had these packages:

```
qt6-webengine 6.6.1-2
qt6-websockets 6.6.2-1
```

and either downgrading qt6-websockets or upgrading the rest of qt solves the problem

for me, i had to run

```bash
sudo pacman -S $(pacman -Qq | grep qt6)
```

which basically upgrades all of qt6 related packages.
On debian the command is different, but you get the idea